# passing a long value from one intent to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a long value from intent of one class to another. But Somehow I dont seem to get the syntax or method to do so. This would solve 90% of my problem. Passing it from a method called intentfunction(setid) in the MainActivity.java to a received intent in SelectOptions.java.

/--MainActivity.java---/

```
private void intentfunction(long setid)
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectOptions.class);
     //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     //editText = new EditText(this);
     etGWid.setText("");   //set the edit text to blank
    //String message = "TestHello";

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, setid);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

SOmething like the above i wish to implement. And here goes the received part of Selectoptions.java

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    long getid = intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, defaultValue)
```

Something like this.

Comment: Well, I am clueless as to how do it. So tried with some inbuilt methods like above. But dont seem to get it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed your intents correctly, now in the receiving activity to get the intent you could use bundles,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras != null) {
    long getid = extras.getString('KEY',default_value);
}
```

Comment: Should the 'KEY" be MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE (Line at which i passed my intent) ??

Comment: yes, the key which the intent was stored with, in your case MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, you may use it without a default value, but you can use a default value for testing purposes

Comment: So basically all I am doing is this:
    if (extras != null) {
            long getid = extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,0);

         }
right ?

Comment: correct, and this should be in the receiving activity of course. I hope i helped you

Comment: Your welcome, good luck with your project! and approve if you liked the answer too :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using getLong() rather than getString()?  Also, there's an intent.getExtraLong() shortcut if you want it.

Comment: @kabuto178: Sorry man. I usually approve it at that instance, but now I just went out and forgot about it.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: Yes, I used getLong()