# Android pass Long value Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I know

```
String value= value;
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("value",value + "");
startActivity(i)
```

and in NextActivity

```
values = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
```

is used to pass the value and get value.. can any one pleaese help me how to pass the long value...

I know
we can get the long value through

```
getIntent().getLongExtra("");
```

can anyone help me how to pass the value ' putExtra ' to my knowledge is used to pass string value..

Comment: Possible duplicate if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671926/passing-a-long-value-from-one-intent-to-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for long values also, you can use:

```
i.putExtra(String name, long value);
```

Comment: Suppose there is no string I need to pass the value of a long

Comment: i.putExtra("key name", long value); Thats it.

Answer (score 10):

For send data

```
i.putExtra("key", long value);
```

For get Intent value in next Activity

```
getIntent().getLongExtra("key", 0);
```

Here `0` denotes default value if you not want putExtra from first Activity then in Next Activity it will take default value as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
send from activity::-> 
Long dd=154235.154
i.putExtra("data", dd);


for get data in another activity ::->>

Long datas=getIntent().getLongExtra("data", 0);
```